# "Could not delete ./" when I use composer in docker

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, dockerfile

When I build my dockerfile, it just show that.

Did anyone tried to use composer in docker?

Or is there any other way to install the flarum into docker?
PS: the user is root.

```
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-2013%24d6b22cfddabf0741ef0c5c720daf4f0a5f17ed112a30074bfeef5007a1e30590.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-2014%2471316c49d46d6c1e66f1d56e3cd12020169065922e83ed72e3319f00146bf8cf.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015-01%244a1f70479a6d65b81b75a0db8f73f0cce3fa08a6f828fe1c93bda72f1943b88d.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-01.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015-04%241bac0fe8d148a91c5820798155f858d8739ec6010801d1c60225c9cfe9f397c1.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-04.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015-07%24c848f45373be754212f1ee20cc125db54480a698619f8f8f22f0a23b5faa4ebb.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-07.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-2015-10%24c322c84a3171f7f09c02691dfcbce028f91bd7a33f517dec9f2901cbcdd73e25.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-10.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-archived%24b1356aa53be4408a11804b506f3383f916bcacdff0f3ac5ec17b3855b7d02290.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest%2420ee33635891a3e02467338b100b4a4afbb76d101faacd8b77595e2de372f325.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json into cache
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/flarum/flarum%24d79b41a5761f33b7816874bad1ab1641c4eec05cd20afa578921adfb13606364.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-flarum$flarum.json into cache
Installing flarum/flarum (v0.1.0-beta.4)
  - Installing flarum/flarum (v0.1.0-beta.4)
Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/flarum/flarum/zipball/4be4e6209f355ffb8d522e8a43c31272d78625d6
    Downloading: 100%         
Writing /root/.composer/cache/files/flarum/flarum/4be4e6209f355ffb8d522e8a43c31272d78625d6.zip into cache from .//81c7ebffe780fe366049c2896d7d82fb
    Extracting archive
Executing command (CWD): unzip './/81c7ebffe780fe366049c2896d7d82fb' -d '/var/www/html/flarum.me/vendor/composer/be9e411c' && chmod -R u+w '/var/www/html/flarum.me/vendor/composer/be9e411c'
    Failed to download flarum/flarum from dist: Could not delete ./: 
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing flarum/flarum (v0.1.0-beta.4)
    Cloning 4be4e6209f355ffb8d522e8a43c31272d78625d6
Executing command (CWD): git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/flarum/flarum.git' './' && cd './' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/flarum/flarum.git' && git fetch composer
Failed: [RuntimeException] Could not delete ./: 



  [RuntimeException]     
  Could not delete ./:   



Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php:216
 Composer\Util\Filesystem->rmdir() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php:154
 Composer\Util\Filesystem->removeDirectoryPhp() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php:128
 Composer\Util\Filesystem->removeDirectory() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Git.php:79
 Composer\Util\Git->runCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php:54
 Composer\Downloader\GitDownloader->doDownload() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/VcsDownloader.php:69
 Composer\Downloader\VcsDownloader->download() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Downloader/DownloadManager.php:199
 Composer\Downloader\DownloadManager->download() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/ProjectInstaller.php:70
 Composer\Installer\ProjectInstaller->install() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer/InstallationManager.php:152
 Composer\Installer\InstallationManager->install() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/CreateProjectCommand.php:323
 Composer\Command\CreateProjectCommand->installRootPackage() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/CreateProjectCommand.php:141
 Composer\Command\CreateProjectCommand->installProject() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/CreateProjectCommand.php:129
 Composer\Command\CreateProjectCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:841
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:167
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:98
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:25


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

How can I solve it?

and my dockerfile below

```
FROM php:fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install git

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/flarum.me && \
    cd /var/www/html/flarum.me && \
    composer create-project flarum/flarum . --stability=beta --prefer-dist -v
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Docker filesystem which doesn't let you to delete current working directly. To solve this issue simply add a path to `composer` create project.

```
FROM php:fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install git

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/flarum.me && \
    cd /var/www/html && \
    composer create-project flarum/flarum flarum.me --stability=beta --prefer-dist -v
```

This should do the job, sorry, I can't test it right now.

Comment: Somebody on IRC told me to try that. I tried that and got another problem. You can see it on http://paste.ubuntu.com/14110196/ . I don't think that is a problem about network. Because I can get the composer online, and I can apt-get install something. So how can I deal with this new problem? Thx :)

Comment: That error suggests that your current working directory has been deleted. But it should be the case because you're out side of project directory with that change. I'm not near my computer later I'll try that.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the man on IRC told me to run it "composer create-project flarum/flarum /var/www/html/flarum.me --stability=beta --prefer-dist -v". then i met the problem, I tried your code again, It runs correctly. Thank you. :) My mistake

Comment: This `The problem is Docker filesystem which doesn't let you to delete current working directly`